# Что такое float в CSS?

Tags: css

Никак не могу разобраться с этим `float`.
Зачем он нужен?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/float

Comment: @MoloF, Этот пережиток прошлого, еще очень нужен и важен...

Comment: Это не пережиток прошлого, просто его нужно использовать по назначению, для обтекания картинок текстом.

Comment: Это инструменты для разных задач

Comment: @MoloF, дико интересно, как ты реализуешь [такое](https://tpverstak.ru/wrapping-content-around-images-css-shapes/)  без `float`?  А это будущее сss

Comment: @Air, присоединяюсь к вопросу)

Comment: @Air впервые вижу такую красивую реализацию этого метода, я ошибся, назвав его устаревшим, видимо я никогда не верстал сайты с подобным содержанием и поэтому не нуждался в этом методе, верстаю я уже пару лет и все мои лендинги не нуждались в подобном, но вот данные примеры дают задуматься мне об повторном использовании этого метода, очень красиво смотрится!

Comment: @MoloF, потому что контент лендинга уже разбит на блоки и там float не нужен. Но попробуй сверстать, например, страницу статьи из журнала, и станет понятно, что замены для float нет.

Comment: @MoloF, рад был тебя переубедить..))

Comment: @Air и вам спасибо за то, что показали реальные примеры которые выглядят очень красиво, возьму на заметку, не делал такого еще никогда

Comment: Как итог float нужен только для обтекания картинок текстом, все остально позиционирование?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Comment: @Dmitry_Maesnes Отметьте моей как ответ как решение

Answer (score 3):

Свойство `float` изначально было задумано для верстки текста с картинками, размещенными слева или справа.

**Пример использования float:**

[image: Пример использования float]

Также раньше, до появления CSS3, это свойство использовалось для позиционирования блоков, однако этот подход имел ряд недостатков и теперь полностью заменен технологией **Flexbox**.

Подробнее про `float`: https://learn.javascript.ru/float